# Grails: russian characters from form

Tags: grails, encoding, localization, character-encoding

Russian characters are shown correctly on the page but incorrectly displayed on the server side if send them from form. For example word `игра` transforms into `Ð¸Ð³ÑÐ°`. I have following lines in `Config.groovy`:

```
grails.views.gsp.encoding = "UTF-8"
grails.converters.encoding = "UTF-8"
```

And following line in the main layout view:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

What should i do to fix it?

Comment: @splix,  POST ajax request. Embedded grails server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data “Ð¸Ð³ÑÐ°” results from UTF-8 encoded “игра” when misinterpreted as ISO-8859-1. It sounds like the HTTP headers specify ISO-8859-1 (or some similar 8-bit encoding); this overrides any `meta` tags.

Comment: Thanks. The problem was solved by setting ajax request `contentType`.